# Snackbar is showing Null pointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife, android-snackbar

Snackbar is showing null pointer exception in fragment.I have implemented Snackbar in implemented in Onfailure error.Snackbar is showing null pointer exception in fragment.I have implemented Snackbar in implemented in Onfailure error.Snackbar is showing null pointer exception in fragment.I have implemented Snackbar in implemented in Onfailure error.

public class SignInOtpFragment extends Fragment {

```
@BindView(R.id.tv_generate_otp)
TextView tvGenerateOtp;
@BindView(R.id.et_mobile)
TextInputEditText etMobile;
@BindView(R.id.constraintLayout)
ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;

String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generate_otp, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, fragmentView);
    getActivity().setTitle("Sign In");

    return fragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@OnClick(R.id.tv_generate_otp)
public void onGenerateOtpClick() {
    validateAndLogin();
}

private void validateAndLogin() {
    if (etMobile.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(null) || etMobile.getText().toString() == "") {
        etMobile.setError("Please Enter a valid mobile number");
    } else if (!etMobile.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern)) {
        etMobile.setError("Please Enter a valid 10 digit number");
    } else {
        registerUser(etMobile.getText().toString());
    }
}

private void registerUser(final String mobileNum) {
    Log.e("--UserTYPE", AppConstants.USER_TYPE);
    Log.e("--MobileNumber", mobileNum);
    ApiClient.makeAPI().postRegister(mobileNum,
            AppConstants.USER_TYPE).enqueue(new Callback<Register>()

    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Register> call, Response<Register> response) {
            ApiClient.printCall(call, response, "Generate OTP");
            String status = response.body().getStatus();               

//                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            SharedPrefsUtils.setStringPreference(getActivity(), AppConstants.BASE_USER, response.body().getUserid());
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(AppConstants.KEY_MOBILE_NUM, mobileNum);
            Fragment fragment = new SignInVerifyOtpFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            //Move to VerifyOtp Fragment
            if (getActivity() instanceof BaseActivity) {
                (((BaseActivity) getActivity())).replaceFragment(R.id.container, fragment);
            }
            //  etMobile.setText("");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Register> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("error", call.toString());
            Log.d("--Throwable", t.toString());
            // Fabric crashlytics issue.
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(mConstraintLayout, "Error occured!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
}
```

my logcat shows :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:136)
       at com.menu28.menu28.view.fragment.SignInOtpFragment$1.onFailure(SignInOtpFragment.java:105)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:77)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: your `mConstraintLayout` is null. You newer write a value in this variable, but try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are inside a fragment i think

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(getView(), "Error occured!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
```

should work for you,Problem is that the view you are passing to snackbar is null.

Answer (score 1):

choose below method for snack bar

```
public static void showMessage(Activity activity) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            activity.getString(R.string.your_msg_string), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    TextView textView = (TextView) snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    snackbar.show();
}
```